# SQL get the value of the unique key count for some table

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, unique

i have an SQL table thet have a unique key column, this key increases by 1 when i insert a new record , suppose i deleted all records in this table so if i add a record after deleting all records the count will continue and i would get for example an id of 97 for that record,question is is there a way in sql to get that value of 97 before adding a the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_NAME)` function to get current identity value of table `TABLE_NAME`.

Comment: well basicly i just defined it as IDENTITY(1,1) how do i get the squence name!?

Comment: question has been tagged SQL Server. There is no concept of a dual tale in SQL Server. Additionally OP refers to an identity field defined on the table itself, not a system-wide sequence

Comment: I believe, you are using SQL Server (I shared the query for oracle). Try `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MY_TABLE')`.

Comment: @cravoori: I saw SQL and answered thinking Oracle. Updated the answer. Hope that is fine.